# OKHttp HEAD Requests - Optimizing for Speed

Tags: android, okhttp

I need to build a URL Head service that delivers all the headers for any URL as quickly as possible.

I've written Unit and Instrumented Tests to see if OKHttp is going to be able to do this for me.

Here's the test

```
class GetHeadersTest {
    @Test
    fun GetHeaders() {
        val startTime: Long = System.currentTimeMillis()
        println("START: ${startTime}")
        val testHeaderURL = "https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/somefolder/image37.jpg"
        println("URL VARIABLE: ${System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime}ms")

        val client = OkHttpClient()
        val clientTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime
        println("OK HTTP CLIENT: ${clientTime}ms")

        val request = Request.Builder().url(testHeaderURL).head().build()
        val requestTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime
        println("OK HTTP REQUEST: ${requestTime}ms")

        val response = client.newCall(request).execute()
        val responseTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime
        println("OK HTTP RESPONSE: ${responseTime}ms: $response")

        println("END: ${System.currentTimeMillis()}")
    }
}
```

The results are quite surprising to me, coming from a browser world.

```
START: 1548683216245
URL VARIABLE: 0ms
OK HTTP CLIENT: 357ms
OK HTTP REQUEST: 370ms
OK HTTP RESPONSE: 750ms: Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=200, message=OK, url=https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/somefolder/image37.jpg}
END: 1548683216995
```

I am instantiating a new `OkHttpClient` in each request, which I would obviously not do in normal circumstances. However a 380ms response time for a simple HEAD request seems extreme. The results are the same in unit and instrumented tests.

I tried with http and the results were as follows

```
START: 1548683574373
URL VARIABLE: 0ms
OK HTTP CLIENT: 338ms
OK HTTP REQUEST: 350ms
OK HTTP RESPONSE: 508ms: Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=200, message=OK, url=http://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/somefolder/image37.jpg}
END: 1548683574881
```

Although this approach is fairly useless as most urls these days are https, the timing is approaching what I would expect for an HTTPS HEAD request.

So the question is - how can I make this any faster? It seems like the SSL connection times are very slow in comparison to the browser world. As it's a HEAD request, could I relax the SSL conditions and ignore any responses?

Is OKHttp the wrong package for making HEAD requests? Should I be going straight to `URLConnection`?

Any advice from anyone much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is don't use OKHttp for this kind of request.

I wrote a Kotlin extension function on java URL instead and it was twice as fast.